# Using paradox to construct tautology for $p\land \lnot p$

Tags: logic, paradoxes

Can a paradox be used to construct a tautology?
$p\land \lnot p$ is logically a contradiction.

Suppose $p$ is the sentence:
"This sentence is a lie"

which we know is paradoxical

is used in conjunction with $\lnot p$
Then is $p\land \lnot p$ a tautology?

Comment: Why not? In a paradox $p\iff \not p$?

Comment: In propositional logic sentences are always either True or False. A paradoxical statement is one that is True iff it is False.

Comment: Thus: if $A$ is true  $\not A$ is true.